# Excel Adding Using a Range of Rangenames

Tags: excel, range, excel-2013, named-ranges, vba

So if I have a range of range names.

MasterRange refering to B2:B4

Then in B2 CRange then CRange referring to C2 is  the value 1
Then in B3 DRange then DRange referring to D2 is  the value 2
Then in B4 ERange then ERange referring to E2 is value 3

Is there a way to use a range to refer to other ranges in order to ad them?

If I =SUM(INDIRECT(MasterRange)) only says 1. It doesn't seem to be adding DRange & ERange

Comment: =sum(indirect(crange & ":" & erange))

Comment: `Range("MasterRange") + Range("BRange") + Range("CRange") `. If the named ranges are scoped to Worksheet, you'll have to qualify to worksheet. This is one way to do it in VBA. There are others.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I mean is there a way I can =SUM(MasterRange) then have that add CRange,DRange, ERange

Comment: @MichaelDowney - 1) Do you want a solution in VBA? 2) Is this reason you are doing so that you can adjust values in `MasterRange` and have it sum whatever other ranges may be there? If not, why are you trying to do it this way versus straight summing the ranges directly?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman if there is a VBA solution that would work.. The issue is if I add say a FRange then I could just expand MasterRange to B2:B5 without having to go resum it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Function below. It's untested, but should give you a great start.

```
Function SumRangeOfRangeNames(SourceRange as Range, SheetName as String) as Double

    Dim celRange as Range
    For each celRange in SourceRange

        Dim Total as Double
        Total = Total + Worksheets(SheetName).Range(SheetName).Value

    Next

    SumRangeOfRangeNames = Total

End Function
```

Call like this from vba

```
Sub Test()

    Dim mySum as Double
    mySum = SumRangeOfRangeNames(Worksheets(Sheet1").Range("MasterRange"),"Sheet1")

    debug.print mySum

End Test
```

Or this way via cell

```
=SumRangeOfRangeNames(MasterRange,"Sheet1")
```